# How does distributed computations on RDD's work in Apache Spark?

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

If I have a very simple Spark program that simply does:

```
val rdd2 = sc.textFile("hdfs:///text.txt")
println(rdd.count)
```

When I submit this spark program to YARN using yarn-cluster:

1. The YARN ResourceManager will negotiate a container and lauch the Spark ApplicationMaster.
2. Then the ApplicationMaster will register itself with the ResourceManager and ask for resources.
3. Ones the resource specifications is obtained from the ResourceManager, the ApplicationMaster will launch the container on the NodeManager.

My question is since the data in Hadoop is distributed across multiple Machines (Let's say that text.txt in the example above is divided up into 3 blocks:

1. Does an Application Master get launched on each and every machine that has a text.txt block?
2. Is the spark executor a software which is already installed on each and every node of the cluster or does the executor gets instantiated into the container that is launched by the ApplicationMaster on the Node?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good question, but probably too big for this forum.

To begin, your assumptions are generally correct but the timing isn't right.

> 1. The YARN ResourceManager will negotiate a container and lauch the Spark ApplicationMaster.
> 2. Then the ApplicationMaster will register itself with the ResourceManager and ask for resources.
> 3. Once the resource specifications is obtained from the ResourceManager, the ApplicationMaster will launch the container on
>      the NodeManager.

If you're using `sc` (the `SparkContext`) then this has already happened. There can be additional work with the ResourceManager if you add or remove executors, but the `SparkContext` only exists after initial resources are allocated.

> 1. Does an Application Master get launched on each and every machine that has a text.txt block?

No, but workers or executors could be launched on any machine that has a block. Alternatively they could be launched on just a single machine. *However* every block is (potentially) read by a worker. In this HDFS case, workers can read from anywhere on the cluster.

> 2. Is the spark executor a software which is already installed on each and every node of the cluster or does the executor gets instantiated
>      into the container that is launched by the ApplicationMaster on the
>      Node?

It can be installed on the nodes, or it can be given to the nodes at run time. The Spark executor is just a jar. I've seen it put into HDFS itself, or placed on each machine in the cluster as a local resource. You could place it in any location that the worker can access.

Comment: Thank you so much for clarifying! My two questions were cleared up but I had a quick question on when you say `but the SparkContext only exists after initial resources are allocated.` When you say initial resources what does that include (like are the initial resources the ApplicationMaster, etc.)?

Comment: Resources are simply one driver and one or more executors, which are all JVMs.